# Freeform option to hide forms from Member Group?

Tags: members, solspace-freeform

As the title suggests, is it possible to hide certain forms from a member group when they are logged in. I am using 5 forms on a site but I only want to allow a member group access to the one form.

UPDATE: This is in the CMS, so Backend.

Many thanks in advance.
Clinton

Comment: Are you referring to front end or back end ?

Comment: Sorry, should have explained. Update post above.

Comment: Yeah, no would be the answer for that one. You can hide the module from member groups but not individual forms

Comment: Bummer :-( Be a nice feature as this area would be similar to the way I would limit access to channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to the front end you can use simple conditionals like this:

```
{if member_group == '3'}show freeform {/if}
```

Examples can be found here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html#logical-operators

In that case: Yeah, no would be the answer for that one. You can hide the module from member groups but not individual forms

Comment: Not what I was looking for but that's good to know. Thanks Stuart.

Comment: Updated my reply. If you could mark it as correct that'd be super.