# Per form permissions for Solspace Freeform for different EE Member Groups: plugin examples that use EE Member Group privileges model

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, members

Expression Engine v2.9.2

I have a paid licensed version of the Solspace Freeform Pro (4.2.2) module. The current permissions model for this plugin does not allow Expression Engine Control Panel per-form viewing and moderation to different EE Member Groups. It allows permission settings on the parent Module only (which means access to all forms). This has been confirmed by Solspace support as of today (2015-03-26).

I have EE Member Groups that should only be permitted to view form submissions (and moderate said form submissions) that they have access to via the EE Control Panel. (I don't want to have to make a front-end templated interface to allow permitted users to approve at that level, although if left with no choice I will do that).

I am comfortable hacking at the Freeform Pro source code to add this feature, but I need some guidance/guidelines on applying the Expression Engine Permissions Member Groups module. I see the Expression Engine docs on the [Cp::allowed_group() method](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/cp.html#allowed-group) but it's pretty slim.

Specifically, if there are any third-party plugins that already use the EE Member Group level permissions model that I can take a peek at the source code to see how it has been done before within the EE Control Panel.

**EDIT 1:** [This person](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18918/) has the same request but didn't get an answer.

**EDIT 2:** [dashEE](https://github.com/mrtopher/dashEE/blob/master/third_party/dashee/widgets/wgt.modify_links.php#L42-L51) does this. That might be enough to get me going and/or I will contact the developer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was also discussed here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/25070/freeform-limit-form-access-to-certain-member-groups-in-cms

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if you're looking for that functionality in the CP (blocking access to specific forms per member group), that is currently not available. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on. :) http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

On the front-end, however, you can do this using regular conditionals. For example, if your group_id for "Marketing Member Group" is 7, then you could do something like this:

```
{if group_id == 7}
   /// Marketing Request form
{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks. This request has already been submitted as a [Feature Request](http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions/topics/75190) a year ago by another user.